# how to return column which has violated the rule (R Validate)

Tags: r, validation

I'm new to R and trying to use the validate package. My questions is how do I return the exact column that is violating the rules I've outlined?

Using violating, I can create a data frame with columns(the unique record ID and the location) but also want to return the name of the column where the violation occurs. So ideally,

[3 column data frame with unique_ID, location, violating_indicator_name][1]

Is this possible? and if so, how?

Thanks :)

[image]

**edit**

Editing because I realized that I could add rule descriptions, is there a way I can add the description of the rule which was validated as a third column to the 'violated' output dataframe

**edit**

```
library(validate)
#> Warning: package 'validate' was built under R version 4.1.3
remove(list = ls())
data(mtcars)

rules <- validator(cyl < 6, gear < 4 )
description(rules) [1] <- "cyl is more than 6 and gear is more than 4."
confronted <- confront(mtcars, rules)

violated <- violating (mtcars[c("cyl", "gear")], confronted)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(validate)
#> Warning: package 'validate' was built under R version 4.1.3

data(cars)

rules <- validator(speed < 25, dist < 100)

confronted <- confront(cars, rules)

violated <- violating(cars, confronted)
violated
#>    speed dist
#> 49    24  120
#> 50    25   85

names(violated)
#> [1] "speed" "dist"

Created on 2022-04-08 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but not quite what I meant, if I take the cars data set example, what I cam trying to achieve is: violated <- violating (cars[c("ID", "car_name")], confronted), however I need a third column that would have the name of the column from the cars data with the violation so that you can see the id number, the car name and then which column to check. The idea is an output that you could give to someone to highlight where potential logical errors are so I need a way of uniquely identifying the record and also a way of identifying in which column/columns the error occurred

Comment: Could you add an expected result to your original question using data(mtcars) or data(cars) as an example?

Comment: I added an edit, hopefully more understandable what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The `confront()` function has an optional argument "key" for adding an identifier column. The key column is added to the output by calling `as.data.frame(out)`.

This is only documented in the vignette, not in the online manual.